# Python RunServer Django script not starting

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/celery.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
```

i just installed pip install celery now i am facing other issue

```
(triad_realty) root@webettonew:~/triad_realty# python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/celery.py", line 10, in <module>
    app = Celery('triad_realty',broker=settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/triad_realty/triad_realty/settings.py", line 17, in <module>
    ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) -2  # (triad_realty/config/settings/common.py - 3 = triad_realty/)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Path'
```

i am struggling to fix this issue please if anybody could help me right away.

i did install environ though the command pip install environ but maybe i need to change the environ.Path but to what if anybody could help me out i would be very thankful i am whole day stuck at it

i am sharing my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for triad_realty project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) -2  # (triad_realty/config/settings/common.py - 3 = triad_realty/)
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR.path('triad_realty')

# Global Variable Type
env_path = str(ROOT_DIR.path('.env'))
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env(env_path)

WEBSITE=env("WEBSITE")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i%be$q6@6@79z(54hvmn#2@6kdygctob2$n!&l-^%9s#h_u(^o'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#     Apps
    'users',
    'investor',
    'projectowner',
    'detail',
    'allauth',  # registration
    'allauth.account',
    'django.contrib.humanize',# registration
    'djcelery',
    'djcelery_email',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'triad_realty.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'triad_realty.wsgi.application'

FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('fixtures')),
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = env('DJANGO_EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases
if env('DEPLOYMENT') == "testing":
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': '',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': env('DBNAME'),
            'USER': env('DBUSER'),
            'PASSWORD': env('DBUSERPASS'),
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root

# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('staticfiles'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static')),
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static/css/')),
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static/js/')),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#wsgi-application

# PASSWORD VALIDATION
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# AUTHENTICATION CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SITE_ID = 1
AUTH_USER_MODEL='users.User'
# Some really nice defaults
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'

ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool('DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION', True)


# Custom user app defaults
# Select the correct user model
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/main'

LOGIN_URL = 'account_login'

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.SignupForm'
# Location of root django.contrib.admin URL, use {% url 'admin:index' %}
ADMIN_URL = r'^admin/'

# Your common stuff: Below this line define 3rd party library settings
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

DEFAULT_EMAIL_FROM = 'no-reply@kidzschool.com'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer formatting your error correctly, please? It is very hard to read.

Comment: i did really sorry i am new to this

Comment: Don't worry, you edited the question correctly. Remember we were all just beginners in the past. SO is not very beginner friendly but is trying to get better and better every day.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I noticed you're running Django 1.9.8, which is no longer supported. If you're starting a new project or just learning Django, I'd strongly recommend to start with Python 3, and Django 2.1, the most recent versions. There have been some major improvements in the past few versions to make things easier for newcomers, specifically the new URL routing syntax.

Comment: actually the thing is i have been working on some project lately of my client and some other developer did it i am trying my best to fix the script and lately fix alot but now i am just stuck on this badly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) into your Python environment?

`pip install celery`

Comment: hello thanks i did this but now i am facing new issue

i did change this in the main part

Comment: Looking at your settings.py, it seems that you are using django environ (https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#environ-path). Maybe you should re-install the correct version of that package for the version of Django you are using (1.9.8)? I ran the following and it worked for me `pip install django-environ` and `import environ; environ.Path(__name__)`